# What will happen if I change the genesis block of a cryptocurrency

Tags: cryptocurrency

I was looking at the code of a cryprocurrency and I thought what will happen to the cryprocurrency if it's genesis block is change.Will a new cryprocurrency can be created if genesis block is changed

Comment: If by change you mean rewrite the block, the hashing functions will fail and you won't be able to push a new block. If by change you mean alter the default values of the genesis block then it would just have different default values. No blockchain can have the genesis block changed.

Answer (score 0):

Genesis block is the first block of a block chain.
Of course, if you change this block, you will be creating another currency or restarting the network.
If you do this in a blockchain that already exists, I believe you may have future problems, as the new nodes will try to pick up the information from the genesis block when you start synchronization.

If the code that you changed is, for example, the one of the BTC and compile it and then put to run, will have no effect on the network, since the main nodes are unaware of this block, making its configuration invalid.